# A comparison between "over" and "during" and "throughout"

Tags: prepositions

I would appreciate it if someone could let me know the semantic nuance between the following self-made sentences:

> It was a hard time. **During** this time, we dealt with many hurdles.

For me, it means is some points while we were dealing with the problems.

> It was a hard time. **throughout** this time, we dealt with many hurdles.

For me it means the whole time while we were dealing with the issues.

> It was a hard time. **Over** this time, we dealt with many hurdles.

How one can explain it in a way that I could differentiate this preposition from the other two? It sounds something between the above mentioned prepositions.

P.S. I've already read all the related threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1

> It was a hard time. During this time, we dealt with many hurdles.
>
> For me, it means is some points while we were dealing with the problems.

2

> It was a hard time. throughout this time, we dealt with many hurdles.
>
> For me it means the whole time while we were dealing with the issues.

3

> It was a hard time. Over this time, we dealt with many hurdles.

1) This means: Part of the time or much of the time we were dealing with many hurdles.

2) I think you are correct. However, it would be more clear to say "throughout this **entire** time"

3) This means: Part of the time or much of the time we were dealing with many hurdles.

> For me, it means is some points while we were dealing with the problems.

This should read "**at some points**".